# nhibernate varbinary(max) byte array mapping

Tags: c#, xml, nhibernate, mapping, sql-server-2014

I looked through all the answers here and elsewhere on the web, but nothing seems to work.
I have a table (sql server 2014) with a varbinary(max) datatype, named "Image"
I'm using NHibernate version 3.3.1.4000, which has some fixes regarding varbinary issues.

this is my current hibernate mapping:

```
   <property name="Image" type="BinaryBlob">
      <column name="Image" sql-type="varbinary(2147483647)" length="2147483647"/>                                             
   </property>
```

I also tried following variations:

```
<property name="Image" type="BinaryBlob"/>

<property name="Image"  length="2147483647"/>
```

this is my (c# class) property:

```
   public virtual byte[] Image { get; set; }
```

I'm getting the familiar error:

```
 ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: String or binary data would be truncated.
```

I have a feeling the answer is staring me right in the face, but I just can't see it.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What dialect are you using?

Comment: I'm not specifying a dialect I think. It was set up by another developer... I initialize a NHibernateHelper like this whith a staticSessionContext that holds a dictionary:   NHibernateHelper.Initialize(new StaticSessionContext(), new Configuration().Configure().BuildSessionFactory());

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got be be doing that somewhere in either code or a config somewhere. I'm using NHibernate 3.3 with the map by code and it's mapping to `VARBINARY(MAX)` without an issue.

Here's my property definition:

```
Property(x => x.Photo, map =>
{
    map.Type(NHibernateUtil.BinaryBlob);
    map.Length(Int32.MaxValue);
});
```

Here's my `SessionFactory` configuration:

```
Configure.DataBaseIntegration(db =>
          {
            db.Dialect<MsSql2008Dialect>();
            db.Driver<SqlClientDriver>();
            db.KeywordsAutoImport = Hbm2DDLKeyWords.AutoQuote;
            db.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
            db.ConnectionStringName = System.Environment.MachineName;
            db.BatchSize = 20;
            db.Timeout = 10;
            db.HqlToSqlSubstitutions = "true 1, false 0, yes 'Y', no 'N'";
          });
```

Note that I'm specifying a Driver and Dialect. `VARBINARY(MAX)` was not supported before the [MsSql2005Dialect](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Dialect/MsSql2005Dialect.cs).

Comment: ah yes I found it in the app.config file:      

 <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect</property>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>

Comment: Sorry about this guys. this mapping does work. I had another column in this table (name column) that was defined as varchar(50) but the value was 51 characters. If only the error message would mention the column perhaps I wouldn't have wasted my and your time on this.... but all is well again :-)